# How to phrase/explode XML data?

Tags: php, xml, phrase

I'm trying to create a printer ink shop from an xml file.

In XML are ID, name, category and description. In description after the words *Toner pasuje do drukarek:* and before *Pokrewne kody:* lists are the printer models to which the ink fits (each printer name starts with the manufacturer's name (e.g. canon, hp, brother)). I would like to phrase these printers and list them one at a time to .

```
<offers>
   <offer>
      <id>37</id>
      <name>
      Toner zamiennik 12a do hp (q2612a) (czarny) - darmowa dostawa w 24h
      </name>
      <description>
      Toner Zamiennik 12A do HP (Q2612A) (Czarny) Toner pasuje do drukarek:HP LaserJet 1010HP LaserJet 1022 NHP LaserJet 3052HP LaserJet 1012HP LaserJet 1022 NWHP LaserJet 3055HP LaserJet 1015HP LaserJet 3015HP LaserJet M1005 MFPHP LaserJet 1018HP LaserJet 3020HP LaserJet M1300 MFPHP LaserJet 1020HP LaserJet 3030HP LaserJet M1319 F MFPHP LaserJet 1020 PlusHP LaserJet 3050HP LaserJet 1022HP LaserJet 3050 ZPokrewne kody: Toner, Tonery, Q2612A, 12A, DT-TH-12A, DrTusz, Hewlett Packard, HP Kod EAN: 5902811000000
      </description>
      <shopcategory>Wkłady -> Laserowe -> Zamienniki -> Tonery</shopcategory>
  </offer>
  <offer>
      <id>38</id>
      <name>
      Toner zamiennik 06a do Canon (c3906a) (czarny) - darmowa dostawa w 24h
      </name>
      <description>
      Toner Zamiennik 06A do Canon (C3906A) (Czarny) Toner pasuje do drukarek:Canon LaserJet 3100Canon LaserJet 3150 XICanon LaserJet 6 L ProCanon LaserJet 3100 SECanon LaserJet 5 LCanon LaserJet 6 L SECanon LaserJet 3100 XICanon LaserJet 5 L XtraCanon LaserJet 6 L XICanon LaserJet 3150Canon LaserJet 5 LFSCanon LaserJet 3150 SECanon LaserJet 6 LPokrewne kody: Toner, Tonery, C3906A, 06A, DT-TH-06A, DrTusz, Hewlett Packard, Canon Kod EAN: 5902811000086          </description>
      <shopcategory>Wkłady -> Laserowe -> Zamienniki -> Tonery</shopcategory>
</offer>
</offers>
```

**Example**

Description is

```
<description>
      Toner Zamiennik 12A do HP (Q2612A) (Czarny) Toner pasuje do drukarek:HP LaserJet 1010HP LaserJet 1022 NHP LaserJet 3052HP LaserJet 1012Pokrewne kody: Toner, Tonery, Q2612A, 12A, DT-TH-12A, DrTusz, Hewlett Packard, HP Kod EAN: 5902811000000
      </description>
```

I want change

```
HP LaserJet 1010HP LaserJet 1022 NHP LaserJet 3052HP LaserJet 1012
```

in

```
<printer>HP LaserJet 1010</printer>
<printer>HP LaserJet 1022 N</printer>
<printer>HP LaserJet 3052</printer>
<printer>HP LaserJet 1012</printer>
```

How can I do it (for example in PHP)?

Thanks

Comment: q=(-_-) Your XML's description-tag is pretty abused! There should be separate tag for each detail, or at least they should be comma separated (fix your `XML`, don't try to develop an `AI` in `PHP`).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the descriptions with the following steps:

### Algorithm

- Find the substring between `"Toner pasuje do drukarek:"` and `"Pokrewne kody"`
- Find the first word in substring to get the `brand`
- Split the substring by `brand`
- Remove the first element (it will be empty)
- Prepend the brand to every split element

### Code

```
$start = 'Toner pasuje do drukarek:';
$end = 'Pokrewne kody';

$descriptions = [...];

$printers = [];
foreach ($descriptions as $description) {
    $startIndex = strpos($description, $start) + strlen($start);
    $endIndex = strpos($description, $end);
    $length = $endIndex - $startIndex;
    $printersAsText = substr($description, $startIndex, $length);
    $firstWord = explode(' ', $printersAsText)[0];
    $printer = explode($firstWord, $printersAsText);
    array_shift($printer);

    $printers[] = array_map(function ($e) use ($firstWord) { return $firstWord . $e; }, $printer);
}

print_r($printers);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/kojIp).